# Is there any way to enable Vulkan rendering for all Chromium-based processes by default?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, electron, environment-variables, chromium

E.g. Chrome, Electron apps, etc. Without setting it, I get graphical glitches on my Linux machine - but it's very tedious to set manually and make custom shortcuts etc. Is there any way to accomplish this by an environmental variable or something else clever?

The arguments that need to be added to each application are normally as follows, but I'm hoping there's some more global method I've overlooked: `--use-vulkan --enable-features=Vulkan`

Comment: Are you building your own Chromium fork? Not sure if policies can be used to override those features but if you are building from source code you can modify the renderer process to pass those arguments when spawning renderer processes

Comment: Alas, I'm not. But the arguments do affect newly spawned windows as is - it's just passing them in the first place to each app is such a pain.